# Shelosha Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gematria for אזכרה

Comment: Is this grandfathered in, or can we still attack the lazy Gematria?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Yad Vashem's "The Untold Stories" Web site](http://www1.yadvashem.org/untoldstories/nowogrodek/nowogrodek.html) (follow the "ghetto" link from that page if your browser uses Javascript), the 233 Jews remaining in the ghetto of Navaradok on September 26, 1943, tried to escape on that date.